# How to find out postgresql password?

Tags: postgresql, passwords, database-connection, psql

This might be a trivial question, but it might me figure out why I am not able to connect to a postgresl db with PHP.

When I connect to a db over terminal I use command:

```
$ psql dbname username
```

And then I get directly into a db

```
dbname=#
```

I am not asked for password.

So when I use any other programming language or software, what am I suppose to state for a password to make a connection to a db?

**Edit**

I am using PHP and I am following this example: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-use-php-with-postgresql/

Particular connection doesnt have password in it:

```
$dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=test user=newbie");
```

Error I get:

```
fe_sendauth no password supplied
```

Checking for hosts over `sudo nano /etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1. localhost
127.0.1.1. ubuntu
```

Same happens with

```
<?php  
$dbuser = 'newbie';  
$dbpass = '';  
$host = 'localhost';  
$dbname='test';  
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
}catch (PDOException $e){  
echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";  
die();  
}  
?>
```

Error

```
Error: SQLState[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using? What is your connection string/function you use? Add some code...

Comment: Try `host=127.0.0.1` instead of `host=localhost`. Another option is to try the exact same string without the `host=localhost ` at all

Comment: did you see my comment?

Comment: @Dekel Same error unfortunatelly if I change it to 127.0.0.1. I am running this Ubuntu on Virtual Machine, dont know does that have any infulance?

Comment: don't think so. what about running without the `host=localhost` at all?

Comment: btw, you can just reset the password if you want - http://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install

Comment: @Dekel Thanks! I changed a password and it works now, but I would really like to know why this happened. Was it because I am superuser over terminal or something else?

Comment: might be several things. yes - if you were superuser you might have these privileges.

Comment: Sorry but cant chat right now, perhaps some other time! Thanks again for your help!:-)